# Steps in developing USB device driver

Tags: windows, usb, device-driver

i have installed Windows DDK and debug view too.
please guide me for writing USB driver for a USB logger device.
if anyone can provide a generic sample code which describes the overall flow 4 driver development..??
i need to know the flow/sequence so tat i can develop the driver as per my device..

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to do something really complicated a simple answer here will only get your started...

- [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/WDK/default.mspx)
- [Driver Development Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx)
- [Universal Serial Bus Driver Development](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usb/usbdevdrvs.htm)

Comment: The last link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the complete Microsoft's documentation for "Developing, Testing, and Deploying Drivers" available at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/creating-a-new-driver. It will take time for reading, understanding and creating issue-free working code. But, this is the only option you have.